# PhpStorm File Template which create more files

Tags: phpstorm

I would like defined file template which create in one step three files. Ideally when I create my defined template "Nette Control" (.php), it must be created too .latte file and .php file (which will be factory for my Nette Control)

Exist some way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer is no :( Please vote for [OC-5351](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-5351) to be notified on any progress

Answer (score 0):

This function was just added in version 2020.3 of PHPstorm and other Jetbrains editors.